# Не подключается openvpn

Tags: openvpn

У меня на linux сервере настроен openvpn, который уже тестился и работал во время тестов.

Сейчас мне потребовалось его снова использовать спустя долгое время. Запустил openvpn на ноуте (windows), всё норм работало.

Запустил openvpn на stb приставке (android) всё норм работало.

С сервером взаимодействую через Putty и там вышла ошибка и работа прекратилась, ну я перезашел, начал снова через openvpn подключаться, а не хочет... И вроде ошибок нет...

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?

Лог из openvpn:

```
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 LZO compression initialized
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1560 D:168 EF:68 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1560 D:1560 EF:60 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '2f2c6498'
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '9915e4a2'
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 Attempting to establish TCP connection with 46.36.219.171:5000
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 TCP connection established with 46.36.219.171:5000
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 46.36.219.171:5000
Fri Sep 14 17:11:38 2018 TLS: Initial packet from 46.36.219.171:5000, sid=c6fd4db2 ed92f6c7
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=MyOrganizationalUnit/CN=Fort-Funston_CA/name=EasyRSA/emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 Validating certificate key usage
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 ++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 00a0
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 VERIFY KU OK
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 Validating certificate extended key usage
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 VERIFY EKU OK
Fri Sep 14 17:11:39 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=MyOrganizationalUnit/CN=server/name=EasyRSA/emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
Fri Sep 14 17:11:41 2018 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri Sep 14 17:11:41 2018 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 14 17:11:41 2018 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri Sep 14 17:11:41 2018 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 14 17:11:41 2018 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Fri Sep 14 17:11:41 2018 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with 46.36.219.171:5000
Fri Sep 14 17:11:43 2018 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Sep 14 17:11:44 2018 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route 10.0.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.0.0.6 10.0.0.5'
Fri Sep 14 17:11:44 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Fri Sep 14 17:11:44 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Fri Sep 14 17:11:44 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Fri Sep 14 17:11:44 2018 Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: Подключение по локальной сети 2
Fri Sep 14 17:11:44 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri Sep 14 17:11:46 2018 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Sep 14 17:11:46 2018 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Fri Sep 14 17:11:46 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Sep 14 17:11:46 2018 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

Comment: А что в логах на сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась перезапуском ноута)